# Laravel Redirecting Back to Main Page

Tags: php, redirect, web, laravel

I'm using Laravel to build an application, which needs user authentication. As such, I used the Auth library to make it. However, when I tested it, when I tried to sign out it first said "Whoops, looks like something went wrong!" and only when I refreshed did it work.

This is the dashboard page

```
@extends('layouts.default')
@section('navbar-content')
<ul class="nav navbar-nav">
<li class="active"><a href="{{ URL::route('Home') }}">Home</a></li>
<li><a href="{{ URL::route('GetSignOut') }}">Sign Out</a></li>
</ul>
<p class="navbar-text navbar-right">Signed in as <a href="" class="navbar-link">{{Auth::user()->name }}</a></p>
@stop

@section('content')
<div class="col-md-3">

</div>
<div class="col-md-6">

</div>
<div class="col-md-3">

</div>
@stop
```

Routes:

```
<?php
Route::get('/', array ('as' => 'Home', 'uses' => 'HomeController@goHome'));
Route::get('/sign-in', array ('as' => 'GetSignIn', 'uses' => 'AuthController@getSignIn'));
Route::post('/sign-in', array('as' => 'PostSignIn', 'uses' => 'AuthController@postSignIn'));
Route::get('/sign-out', array('as' => 'GetSignOut', 'uses' => 'AuthController@getSignOut'));
```

Authentication Controller:

```
<?php 
class AuthController extends BaseController {
    public function getSignIn() {
        return View::make('sign-in');
    }

    public function postSignIn() {
        $validator = Validator::make(Input::all(), array(
            'email' => 'required|max:255',
            'password' => 'required'
        ));

        if ($validator->fails()) {
            return Redirect::route('GetSignIn')->withErrors($validator);
        }

        $auth = Auth::attempt(array(
            'email' => Input::get('email'),
            'password'  => Input::get('password')
        ), false);

        if (!$auth) {
            return Redirect::route('GetSignIn')->withErrors(array ('Invalid credentials'));
        }

        return Redirect::route('Home');
    }

    public function getSignOut() {
        Auth::logout();
        return Redirect::route('Home');
    }
}
```

Comment: what version of Laravel framework ?  4.1.?

Comment: in the config/app set debug => true and post the important part

Comment: I am using version 4.1.28

Comment: Illuminate \ Database \ QueryException
SQLSTATE[42S22]: Column not found: 1054 Unknown column 'remember_token' in 'field list' (SQL: update `users` set `updated_at` = 2014-04-27 16:31:51, `remember_token` = U8S5PreLePBb6vQTDMmKz1VpWl66JtFlzhVYnC9bX4bxAfRB6LXKyJQjIMKv where `id` = 7)

Answer (score 4):

Take a look at [this upgrade guide](http://laravel.com/docs/upgrade#upgrade-4.1.26).

You need to add a new, `nullable` `remember_token` column of `VARCHAR(100)` to your `users` table.